# RigidBody MovePosition lags behind another RigidBody

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm doing a VR game and the camera is controlled through a RigidBody:

```
private void FixedUpdate() {
   Vector2 primaryAxis = OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Axis2D.PrimaryThumbstick);
   ...
   rigidbody.AddForce(velocityChange, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
```

Now I want to move the hand of the player, that also has a RigidBody so I do:

```
private void FixedUpdate() {
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(mainPlayer.transform.TransformPoint(controller));
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MoveRotation(mainPlayer.transform.rotation * rot);
}
```

When I use the thumbstick to move the main character the hand does move along with it but it visibly lags behind. I'm aware of the difference between the run loop of the game engine and physics engine but still can't wrap my head around it.

Edit:

My guess is that when I do `AddForce` on the camera the transform doesn't get updated until after all the FixedUpdates are called, so the hand doesn't have access to the freshest transform.

And the only way I can fix it is through some smart joint setup.

[image]

Comment: This might be interesting to read: https://www.kinematicsoup.com/news/2016/8/9/rrypp5tkubynjwxhxjzd42s3o034o8

Comment: It was something different but it's a great article

Answer (score 2):

Here's what's happening:

When I call `AddForce` on the camera in `FixedUpdate` the transform won't change until later, after all `FixedUpdate`s are called and the physics engine moves on to simulation calculations.

That's why when I call `MovePosition` in the hand it'll always be one physics tick behind.

I fixed it by predicting where the *should* be in the current physics frame.

```
    //Get the camera velocity after `AddForce`
    cameraVelocity = cameraVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

    //I know the velocity so I know where the camera will end up once the physics engine sets all the transforms
    //I'm pseudo-simulating the current physics step

    mainPlayer.transform.position += vel;

    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(mainPlayer.transform.TransformPoint(controller));
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MoveRotation(mainPlayer.transform.rotation * rot);

    mainPlayer.transform.position -= vel;
```

And everything's smooth now!

Answer (score 0):

You should move your logic away from Fixed update as it is not called every frame, sometimes it happens twice a frame sometimes on every two frames.

> FixedUpdate is often called more frequently than Update. It can be called multiple times per frame, if the frame rate is low and it may not be called between frames at all if the frame rate is high. All physics calculations and updates occur immediately after FixedUpdate. When applying movement calculations inside FixedUpdate, you do not need to multiply your values by Time.deltaTime. This is because FixedUpdate is called on a reliable timer, independent of the frame rate.

You can read [this article](https://forum.unity.com/threads/the-truth-about-fixedupdate.231637/) for a better explanation, and you also have [official documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html).

Comment: It's the opposite AFAIK: you NEED to perform your Rigidbody updates in FixedUpdate. 

`In a script, the FixedUpdate function is recommended as the place to apply forces and change Rigidbody settings (as opposed to Update, which is used for most other frame update tasks)`

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html?_ga=2.5896369.38390628.1574934769-1357256513.1564747151